# Preg_match_all how to correctly get all info?

Tags: php, arrays, web-scraping, preg-match-all

Can't understand how correctly get all info from web, not just one row but all.

This script produces the output : Array  Array  Array   Array and only one row.

```
<table id="rounded-corner" width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td>Nuotrauka</td>
      <td>Pavadinimas</td>
      <td>miestas</td>
      <td>metai</td>
      <td>kaina</td>
    </tr>
  <?
  $url = "My Link";
  $contents = file_get_contents($url);

  preg_match_all("|<span class=\"ttitle2\">(.*?) </span>|U",$contents,$pavadinimas);
  preg_match_all("|<span class=\"ttitle3\">(.*?)</span>|U",$contents,$miestas);
  preg_match_all("|<span class=\"ttitle1\">(.*?)</span>|U",$contents,$metai);
  preg_match_all("|<span class=\"ttitle1\" style='float: left;'>(.*?)<br />|U",$contents,$kaina);
  preg_match_all("/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si", $contents, $img_link); 

  $output = "<tr><td><img src=$img_link></td><td>$pavadinimas</td><td>$miestas</td><td>$metai</td><td>$kaina</td></tr>";

  print_r($output);


 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share $contents html to check it?

Comment: Please check posted answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello Lukas, go with my posted answer. I think it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It is extracting data as required.

```
    <table style="border: 1px solid black;" id="rounded-corner" width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Nuotrauka</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Pavadinimas</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">miestas</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">metai</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;">kaina</td>
    </tr>
<?php
  $url = "put_your_url";
  $contents = file_get_contents($url); 

  preg_match_all('/<span class="ttitle2".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contents,$pavadinimas); 

  preg_match_all('/<span class="ttitle3".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contents,$miestas); 

  preg_match_all('/<span class="ttitle1".*?>(.*?)<\/span>/',$contents,$metai_kaina); 

  foreach($metai_kaina[0] as $key=>$metai_kaina_val){ 
    if($key%2==0)
    $metai[] = strip_tags($metai_kaina_val);
    else  
    $kaina[] = strip_tags($metai_kaina_val);  
  }

  preg_match_all('/<img .*?(?=src)src=\"([^\"]+)\"/si', $contents, $img_link);

  for($i=0; $i<count($pavadinimas[0]); $i++){
    echo '<tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="'.$img_link[1][$i+2].'"></td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$pavadinimas[0][$i].'</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$miestas[0][$i].'</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$metai[$i].'</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$kaina[$i].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Lukas, All the values are in arrays. Now you only have to integrate with your look.

Comment: ok..I will help you to use. Can share with me a mock-up or screens-hot to display the values in which manner?

Comment: Lukas, I have updated the post. Just copy and replace with your and put the url. By using this you can display the extracted data in a html table.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match_all makes deep complex search. Maximum it'll be two dimentional array. Read [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

> how to correctly get all info?

For this to find out you just dump out all the result info:

```
print_r($pavadinimas);
print_r($miestas);
...
```

> but i need that all info put in table

Be little more inventive; if `$pavadinimas` is 2d array:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($p in $pavadinimas){
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach($item in $p){
         echo '<td>' ,  $item , '</td>' ;
    } 
    echo '</tr>';   
}
echo '</table>';
```

### Note

To invert the 2d array order you just use flag (**PREG_PATTERN_ORDER** or **PREG_SET_ORDER**) in the *preg_match_all* (see **flag** section in docs). Thus you will have your table with other order.

Answer (score 0):

The `$matches` parameter of the function will always be an array - you need to process the variable before adding them to the output string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

As far as I'm aware you can't `print_r` a mixture of string and array.

Comment: Start by taking a look at the matches you're getting - as @Igor Savinkin pointed out:

`print_r($pavadinimas);
print_r($miestas);
...`

Answer (score 0):

If all matchings return the same number of results, which seems to be implied by your $output structure, iterate over one of them:

```
$output = '';
foreach ($pavadinimas[1] as $index => $match) { 
    $output .= '<tr><td><img src=' . $img_link[1][$index] . '></td><td>' . $match . '</td><td>' . $miestas[1][$index] . '</td><td>' . $metai[1][$index] . '</td><td>' . $kaina[1][$index] . '</td></tr>';    
}
```